Cannot import OllamaEmbedding from llama_index.embeddings.ollama
I get error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 from llama_index.embeddings.ollama import OllamaEmbedding

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.embeddings.ollama'

I have both llama-index, llama-index-embeddings-ollama installed using pip.

Release today https://pypi.org/project/llama-index/

@toyotaSupra what are you trying to say? do you mean that the newer versions do not work like that anymore? if so, can you provide any example?

You need to install llama-index-embeddings-ollama library along with llama-index and it will work.
$ python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun  7 2023, 12:45:35) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from llama_index.embeddings.ollama import OllamaEmbedding
>>>


You can download it using:
pip install llama-index-embeddings-ollama

